# Sahaba who married Christians and Jews

Tags: history, sahaba, interfaith-marriage

I wanted to know about the Sahabas who married christians and jews and whose wives did not accept Islam even after the marriage, for e.g. Muawiya I had one wife who was a jacobit christian, though i don't know if she accepted Islam or not, is there any other Sahaba ?

Comment: What are you expecting? A full list? Examples? I mean in first place this doesn't seem to be related to Islam but to history of some Muslims (the sahaba), assuming historians have enough information about all of them, there's no guarantee that we would know all about their families especially if those were not "famous" sahaba. Like those known by hadith scholars, as if we assume that at fath Mekka there have been some 100000 sahabi present I'm afraid not even half of them are known or quoted in these books.

Comment: No, not full list, of course not, this is not possible, but at least some, like I mention Muawiya 1 as an example, indeed this is not related to the ibaadaat of Islam but surely to its history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Tafsir: *Ahkam ul Quran* by *[Abu Bakr Ahmad bin Ali Al-Razi Al-Jassas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ja%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%A3%C4%81s)*

[Surah Maidah, section on marriage with the people of the Book](https://shamela.ws/book/23579/1094):

> وروي أن عثمان بْن عفان تزوج نائلة بنت الفرافصة الكلبية وهي نصرانية
> وتزوجها على نسائه وروي عن طلحة بْن عبيد الله أنه تزوج يهودية من أهل
> الشام
>
> It is narrated that Uthman Bin Affan married Na'ila bint al-Furafisa, of
> the tribe of Kalb, and she was a Christian, and he married her on
> previous (muslim) wives. And it is narrated about Talha bin
> Ubaid-Ullah that he married a Jewess from Syria.

[Surah Baqarah, section on marriage with polytheists](https://shamela.ws/book/23579/414)

> وروي عن حذيفة أيضا أنه تزوج يهودية وكتب إليه عمر أن خل سبيلها , فكتب
> إليه حذيفة : أحرام هي ؟ فكتب إليه عمر : لا , ولكن أخاف أن تواقعوا
> المومسات منهن
>
> It is narrated about Huzaifah that he married a Jewess. When Umar
> found out about it, he wrote to Huzaifah to seperate from the woman.
> Huzaifah wrote in reply that "Is she haram for me?" Umar replied:
> "No, but I fear that you may take the immoral ones among them".

So there are narrations about at least three companions that they married Jews or Christians:

- [Uthman ibn Affan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uthman)
- [Talhah ibn Ubaydullah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talhah)
- [Hudhayfah ibn al-Yaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudhayfah_ibn_al-Yaman)

Among them, Na'ila, the wife of Uthman, eventually accepted Islam but apparently sometime after the marriage.

Comment: Jazak Allah for this answer, this question might be of interest to you: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39107/interfaith-marriage-in-islam